# Python - remove last 2 characters from the end of file file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, io

I have a `JSON` file that always contains one JSON Array. Eg:

```
[
{....},
{....},
{....}
]
```

I'm looking for a memory-efficient way to "open" the JSON - remove the right square bracket, find the closest right curly brace, add a comma after the brace and write `\n` so I can keep writing JSON objects. JSONs can be spread into multiple rows.

It'd look like this:

```
[
{....},
{....},
{..
   ..},
<CURSOR>
```

How would you do that without loading JSON into the memory?

PS: The end of the file could look like this also:

```
...}]
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use `json.load()` to read the whole thing into a Python list, append to the list, then use `json.dump()` to write it back to the file.

Comment: If the JSON is so big that this causes a memory problem, you probably shouldn't be using a JSON file in the first place, you should use a database.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of code, try these lines:

```py
import os
with open("./Data/test.json", 'rb+') as fh:
    fh.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    fh.truncate()
```

Comment: It's probably worth verifying that the file has a trailing `]` _and_ the question premise is troubling, but this seems practical